# jquery ajax how should it format dates?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, date

I use jquery to communicate with a REST API. (ASP.net Web API).

I create a simple object and then use jquery to 'PUT' it on the server:

```js
var myObject = {
  name: 'just a name',
  createDate: new Date()
}
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://myServer/api/person/1',
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'put',
  data: myObject
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Looking at the network traffic in Firebug I can see that my createDate propery gets sent over the line as:

```
Tue Feb 02 2016 14:40:26 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

This would be the default rendering of a `new Date().toString()`

Not remarkably my API does not like this, it accepts dates in several formats and really handles the normal JSON version very well:

```
new Date().toJSON()
results to: "2016-02-02T13:45:37.069Z"
```

How to deal with this? I would prefer not to have to post my object by 'manually' converting every date to JSON, this takes the whole ease of working with complex objects out of it.

What I could to (warning really dirty trick coming up), override the default toString method of the date object:

```
Date.prototype.toString = new Date().toJSON
```

This works... but... YUCK!

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems from the prose of your question that you're talking about what you send *from* the client *to* the server, but your `ajax` call isn't sending JSON to the server at all, it's sending the usual URI-encoded format. `dataType` tells jQuery what you're expecting *back* from the server, not what you're *sending* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` takes a "replacer" argument which can be several things, including a function that can be used to generate the appropriate values for properties. You could use that to replace dates with a format that your server would then detect and turn back into dates.

Example:

```js
var data = {
  dt: new Date()
};
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value) {
  if (value instanceof Date) {
    return value.toISOString();
  }
  return value;
});
```

Or there's Microsoft's preferred `/Date(mssinceepoch)/`:

```
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value) {
  if (value instanceof Date) {
    return "/Date(" + value.getTime() + ")/";
  }
  return value;
});
```

Either way, your server piece would have to detect those (by the name of the key, or by the pattern of the value, etc) and convert them back to dates.

Your `ajax` call would change to:

```
var myObject = {
  name: 'just a name',
  createDate: new Date()
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://myServer/api/person/1',
  contentType: 'json',
  method: 'put',
  data: JSON.stringify(myObject, myReplacerFunction)
});
```

The only difference is calling `JSON.stringify`. Also, you had put `dataType: 'json'` in your call, but if you're **sending** JSON, you use `contentType` to tell the server what it is, not `dataType`; `dataType` tells jQuery what you're expecting the server to send *back*.

Comment: Hi T.J. Thanks for the info, 

I was fiddling along these lines already. 

I think this will work without using the replacer. When calling JSON.stringify() on an date object, the date is first handled by Date.toJSON, this already converts to ISO date.

Leaves me with the fact that I actually don't want ISO dates, just localDates, but I guess I could use the replacer to handle that!

Comment: Thanks T.J. I've added the worked out solution below.

Answer (score 0):

So, Thanks to T.J.'s answer and some further exploration, this is what I came up with, someone might find it usefull.

Objective: post an object containing dates, have them sent over the line as JSON. icing on the cake: using LOCALIZED date objects instead of UTC dates, because I happen to like that ;)

```js
/* 
 add a toJSONlocal method to the date object
 takes the date, corrects the time zone and gives json output without the 'Z' at the end 
*/
Date.prototype.toJSONlocal = function() {
 var local = new Date(this); 
 local.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() - this.getTimezoneOffset());
 return local.toJSON().substring(0,23)
}

/* 
 replacer function to use with JSON.stringify() 
 checks if the received string is an ISO Date, if so make it local.
*/
jsonDateLocalizer = function(key, value) {
 if(typeof value == 'string' && value.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}Z/)) {
  return(new Date(value).toJSONlocal())
 }
 return value;
};



var myObject = {
  name: 'Bobby Tables',
  createDate: new Date()
}
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://myServer/api/person/1', // send it here
 dataType: 'json', // expect json in return
 method: 'put', // let's do a PUT request
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", //tell the server I'm sending json.
 data: JSON.stringify(myObject, jsonDateLocalizer) // here you go, json data, with dates the way I like 'em
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```